# Stopwords are not working for keyword searching

Tags: php, stop-words, keyword-search

I have a code in PHP for keywords searching from Bengali texts. It gives output but I'm facing three problems -

1. It's not ignoring the stopwords array I declared.
2. It suppose to give 10 keywords but sometimes it gives 11/12/13 keywords.
3. It gives some same words as output sometimes.

This is my code :

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?action=extractKeyWords" method="POST">
        <div class="heading1">গীতিকার অনুসন্ধান</div>
        <div class="heading2">Find Out Lyricist</div>
        <label>Insert a text file of Bengali song lyrics</label>
        <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" class="upload">
        <input type="submit" value="GO!" name="btn" class="button">


        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['action']) == 'extractKeyWords') {
            $target_path = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

            function extractKeyWords($string) {
                mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
                $stopwords = array('যায়','এরপর', 'আমি', 'একটি', 'এবং', 'আর', 'অথবা', 'তুমি', 'সে', 'ওরা', 'এ', 'ঐ', 'ও', 'কিভাবে', 'মধ্যে', 'থেকে', 'যেভাবে', 'হয়', 'বা', 'এর', 'এক', 'তার', 'উপর', 'ওখানে', 'সেখানে', 'তা', 'সেথা', 'ছিল', 'হবে', 'কি', 'কখন', 'কোথায়', 'কে', 'সাথে');
                //$string = preg_replace('/[\pP]/u', '', trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/iu', '', mb_strtolower($string))));
                $string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/i', '', $string);
                $matchWords = array_filter(explode(' ', $string), function ($item) use ($stopwords) {
                    return !($item == '' || in_array($item, $stopwords) || mb_strlen($item) <= 2 || is_numeric($item));
                });
                $wordCountArr = array_count_values($matchWords);
                arsort($wordCountArr);
                $wordCountArr = array_slice($wordCountArr, 0, 10);
                return $wordCountArr;
            }

            $file = file_get_contents($target_path, true);
            $words = extractKeyWords($file);

            Print "<div class='output'>Keywords: " . implode(',', array_keys($words)) . "<div>";
        }
        ?>
    </form>
```

Sample Text:

```
ধিতাং ধিতাং বোলে এ মাদলে তান তোলে,
তার আনন্দ উচ্ছলে আকাশ ভোরে জোছনায়,
আই ছুটে সকলে এই মাটির ধরা তলে,
আজ হাসির কলরোলে নতুন জীবন গড়ি আই,
আয় রে আয় লগন বয়ে যায়,
মেঘ গুর গুর করে চাদের সীমানায়,
পারুল বোন ডাকে চম্পা ছুটে আয়,
বর্গিরা সব হাঁকে কোমর বেধে আয়,
আয় রে আয় আয় রে আয়,
আয় রে আয় আয় রে আয়
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace()` will not work properly on multi-byte strings, which you're using.

You would instead need to use `mb_ereg_replace()` documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php).